# Delete unrelated part of code in edit

Tags: discussion, edits

Today I had faced [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228265/attribute-error-message#42228319), and I tried to find the line that had the error in it where the OP had a question about it, but other lines in the posted code were totally unrelated to problem.

After that I thought that I should edit the question and delete all unrelated code parts and just leave the line that contains the error. Should I do that or not? However, this is just an example. Should we delete all unrelated parts of code in editing?

Comment: Editing code is always problematic. If there's too much code, you can close as off-topic: no mcve, because the code shown is not _minimal_. 

If you're absolutely certain you know what you're doing, you can reduce the code in a question to an MCVE indeed - IMHO.